# How do I apply BOTH Bootstrap styling class to an HTML DropDownFor combined with a default value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, html-helper

There doesn't appear to be an overload that supports this.  I am currently using Overload 2

DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper, Expression>, IEnumerable, IDictionary)

Here is my call

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BandLeaderId, Model.BandLeaderList, Model.BandLeaderId)
```

I want to add:

```
new { @class = "form-control" }
```

The 3rd overload and 6th overload will take this an object, but then they do NOT include this, IDictionary to set the default value.

Do I have to use javascript after the fact to set the styling?

Comment: I don't believe that answers my question.  Both sets of documentation (DropDownList and DropDownListFor) , to me, show how you can include the default selected value for the list **OR** styling....not both.

Comment: Its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BandleaderId, Model.BandLeaderList, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Edit as per Stephen's comment:**

Use this form instead:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BandLeaderId, Model.BandLeaderList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Since your control is bound to `BandLeaderId`, as in `m => m.BandLeaderId`, whatever value you set in the model is what this control will use.

I always forget this nuance about the `DropDownListFor` until I try to use it in my own projects and then remember that it doesn't work the way the documentation might lead you to believe. Thanks Stephen!

**Original answer below**

---

The overload that you probably want is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.Object%29):

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

Note, however, that you want to supply your default value to the `SelectList`. As in:

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField,
    object selectedValue
)
```

Applying it to your situation:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BandLeaderId,
    new SelectList(Model.BandLeaderList, "BandLeaderId", "BandLeaderName", Model.BandLeaderId),
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

My assumptions here are that your `Model.BandLeaderList` contains an `IEnumerable` with properties of `BandLeaderId` and `BandLeaderName`. Substitute `Key` and `Value` if `BandLeaderList` is a `Dictionary` object instead.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!

Comment: This is wrong. Model binding works by binding to the value of the property and the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is ignored by the `DropDownListFor` method (internally the method builds its own `SelectList`)

Comment: Good catch @StephenMuecke ! Updated the answer to reflect this.